# Can I create a chrome extension, that will redirect me to html document on my computer when I go to certain url's?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to make some sort of 'website blocker' (?) chrome extension, that redirects to html page that says website is blocked.

I already have manifest.json:

```
 {
  "name": "Redirector",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "...",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["content.js"]
   }
   ],
  "permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

and my content.js looks like this:

```
window.location.assign("index.html");
```

but every time i enter some website it redirects me from https://currentwebsite.com/ to https://currentwebsite.com/index.html, but i want it to redirect to index.html.

*Sorry for every language mistake.
**I am starting with js, dont flame me for bad code pls.

Comment: I don't know what your problem exactly is, but maybe this helps, [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting "index.html" indeed won't work, your path should look like "http://index.html", though I don't think that'd be a page that you want to be redirected to. I suggest changing it to simply

```
window.location.assign("https://google.com");
```

or you may want to use that to redirect back to previous page:

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: so is it impossible to redirect to html file ? If not i will try to put it on 000webhost or something

Comment: I don't get which html file you're refering to. If it's on your local pc, yeah you can use it just put the path of it.

Comment: I mean html file on my pc, sorry.

Comment: So lets say the file is at your Desktop, it should look like this: "file:///C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/index.html"

Comment: It's not working, just nothing happens and normally enters website :/

Comment: oh and i get an error: Not allowed to load local resource